# Delete model from GPU/CPU in Pytorch

Tags: python, memory, pytorch, gpu, cpu

I have a big issue with memory. I am developing a big application with GUI for testing and optimizing neural networks. The main program is showing the GUI, but training is done in thread. In my app I need to train many models with different parameters one after one. To do this I need to create a model for each attempt. When I train one I want to delete it and train new one, but I cannot delete old model. I am trying to do something like this:

```
del model
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

but GPU memory doesn't change,

then i tried to do this:

```
model.cpu()
del model
```

When I move model to CPU, GPU memory is freed but CPU memory increase.
In each attempt of training, memory is increasing all the time. Only when I close my app and run it again the all memory is freed.

Is there a way to delete model permanently from GPU or CPU?

Edit:
Code:

Thread, where the procces of training take pleace:

```
class uczeniegridsearcch(QObject):
     endofoneloop = pyqtSignal()
     endofonesample = pyqtSignal()
     finished = pyqtSignal()
     def __init__(self, train_loader, test_loader, epoch, optimizer, lenoftd, lossfun, numberofsamples, optimparams, listoflabels, model_name, num_of_class, pret):
          super(uczeniegridsearcch, self).__init__()
          self.train_loaderup = train_loader
          self.test_loaderup = test_loader
          self.epochup = epoch
          self.optimizername = optimizer
          self.lenofdt = lenoftd
          self.lossfun = lossfun
          self.numberofsamples = numberofsamples
          self.acc = 0
          self.train_loss = 0
          self.sendloss = 0
          self.optimparams = optimparams
          self.listoflabels = listoflabels
          self.sel_Net = model_name
          self.num_of_class = num_of_class
          self.sel_Pret = pret
          self.modelforsend = []
          

     def setuptrainmodel(self):

          if self.sel_Net == "AlexNet":
               model = models.alexnet(pretrained=self.sel_Pret)
               model.classifier[6] = torch.nn.Linear(4096, self.num_of_class)
          elif self.sel_Net == "ResNet50":
               model = models.resnet50(pretrained=self.sel_Pret)
               model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, self.num_of_class)
          elif self.sel_Net == "VGG13":
               model = models.vgg13(pretrained=self.sel_Pret)
               model.classifier[6] = torch.nn.Linear(model.classifier[6].in_features, self.num_of_class)
          elif self.sel_Net == "DenseNet201":
               model = models.densenet201(pretrained=self.sel_Pret)
               model.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(model.classifier.in_features, self.num_of_class)

          elif self.sel_Net == "MNASnet":
               model = models.mnasnet1_0(pretrained=self.sel_Pret)
               model.classifier[1] = torch.nn.Linear(model.classifier[1].in_features, self.num_of_class)

          elif self.sel_Net == "ShuffleNet v2":
               model = models.shufflenet_v2_x1_0(pretrained=self.sel_Pret)
               model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, self.num_of_class)

          elif self.sel_Net == "SqueezeNet":
               model = models.squeezenet1_0(pretrained=self.sel_Pret)
               model.classifier[1] = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, self.num_of_class, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
               model.num_classes = self.num_of_class

          elif self.sel_Net == "GoogleNet":
               model = models.googlenet(pretrained=self.sel_Pret)
               model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, self.num_of_class)

          return model
     def train(self):
          
          for x in range(self.numberofsamples):



               torch.cuda.empty_cache()


               modelup = self.setuptrainmodel()
               

               device = torch.device('cuda')

               optimizerup = TableWidget.setupotimfun(self, modelup, self.optimizername, self.optimparams[(x, 0)],
                                                      self.optimparams[(x, 1)], self.optimparams[(x, 2)],
                                                      self.optimparams[(x, 3)],
                                                      self.optimparams[(x, 4)], self.optimparams[(x, 5)])

               modelup = modelup.to(device)



               

               best_accuracy = 0.0
               


               train_error_count = 0
               
               for epoch in range(self.epochup):

                    for images, labels in iter(self.train_loaderup):
                         images = images.to(device)
                         labels = labels.to(device)
                         optimizerup.zero_grad()
                         outputs = modelup(images)
                         loss = TableWidget.setuplossfun(self, lossfun=self.lossfun, outputs=outputs, labels=labels)
                         self.train_loss += loss
                         loss.backward()
                         optimizerup.step()
                         train_error_count += float(torch.sum(torch.abs(labels - outputs.argmax(1))))
                    self.train_loss /= len(self.train_loaderup)

                    test_error_count = 0.0

                    for images, labels in iter(self.test_loaderup):
                         images = images.to(device)
                         labels = labels.to(device)
                         outputs = modelup(images)
                         test_error_count += float(torch.sum(torch.abs(labels - outputs.argmax(1))))

                    test_accuracy = 1.0 - float(test_error_count) / float(self.lenofdt)

                    print('%s, %d,%d: %f %f' % ("Próba nr:", x+1, epoch, test_accuracy, self.train_loss), "Parametry: ", self.optimparams[x,:])

                    self.acc = test_accuracy
                    self.sendloss = self.train_loss.item()
                    self.endofoneloop.emit()


               self.endofonesample.emit()

               modelup.cpu()
               
               del modelup,optimizerup,device,test_accuracy,test_error_count,train_error_count,loss,labels,images,outputs
               torch.cuda.empty_cache()
               

          self.finished.emit()
```

How I call thread in main block:

```
              self.qtest = uczeniegridsearcch(self.train_loader,self.test_loader, int(self.InputEpoch.text()),
                                              self.sel_Optim,len(self.test_dataset), self.sel_Loss,
                                              int(self.numberofsamples.text()), self.params, self.listoflabels,
                                              self.sel_Net,len(self.sel_ImgClasses),self.sel_Pret)

              self.qtest.endofoneloop.connect(self.inkofprogress)
              self.qtest.endofonesample.connect(self.inksamples)
              self.qtest.finished.connect(self.prints)
              testtret = threading.Thread(target=self.qtest.train)
              testtret.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the model creation code is run iteratively inside a loop,I suggest the following

1. Put code for model creation, training,evaluation and model deletion code inside a separate function and call that function from the loop body.
2. Call `gc.collect()` after the function call

The rational for first point is that the model creation, deletion and cache clearing would happen in a separate stack and it would force the GPU memory clearance when the method returns.